# firefox addon page url

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox addon, in which I have to obtain the URL of the calling web page.
My calling web page is opened as a radwindow inside `default.aspx`.
When I use `window.content.document.location.href`, it returns the default page address.

How can I obtain the URL of the opened radwindow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this example,

```
 function GetRadWindow() {   
    var oWindow = null;   
    if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow; //Will work in Moz in all cases, including clasic dialog   
    else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow; //IE (and Moz az well)   
    return oWindow;   
}   

GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.location.href;
```

Comment: i used this function, but it returns null. i need to have access to the radwindow url in my xul file.

Comment: I found the answer myself, radwindows are iframes, so inorder to get the first radwindow you should use :
var frames = window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
and the radwindow is frames[0].
in my case i had two nested radwindows, so i used 
var frames = window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var result = frames[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];